# C# Service Reference Java -> C#

Tags: c#, java, service, wsdl

First let me say that this is a less then ideal situation.  I do not possess a copy of the original WSDL to identify what changed; I'm also working with developers over the wall who are unable to help.  My application is developed in Visual Studio 2010 consuming a service end point written in Java.

I have a C# application with has a Service Reference, will call it arbitrarily Widget.  Widget has a method DoWork which takes four arguments, argument01, argument02, argument03 & argument04.

The method signature of my generated C# code is such

```
public DoWorkResponse DoWork(string argument01, int argument02, bool argument03, int argument04)
```

Recently a new method was added and I was told to update my reference.  When I did, my signature changed from the above to:

```
public DoWorkResponse DoWork(DoWork DoWork1)
```

where DoWork is

```
partial class DoWork
{
    string argument01;

    int argument02;

    bool argument03;

    int argument04;
```

}

I'm sorry that I am unable to provide original code but as most of you can understand this is not possible.

So basically I'm looking for some insight as to what might have changed on the java side to cause Visual Studio to generate differently then before.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It looks like the `DoWork` method was refactored at the same time as the new method was added.

Comment: That was my thought as well but the developer who original wrote the end point is no longer on staff and the one assigned to it is afraid to delve into it for fear of breaking the black box.
I'm pretty sure this is the bit of wsdl that's causing the trouble.
`<xs:element name="DoWork">`
`<xs:complexType>`
`<xs:sequence>`

Comment: @clichekiller You say _what might have changed on the java side to cause Visual Studio to generate differently then before_. There's no "might" to it; at some point, the method exposed by the service had its signature changed and the service was recompiled/redeployed. That change might have been before the new method was added, but it didn't get deployed to the server until the recent changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps the `parameterStyle` element of the [SOAPBinding](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/jws/soap/SOAPBinding.html) annotation was changed making the parameter style bare instead of wrapped.  They could try adding this to their service definition:

```
@SOAPBinding(parameterStyle = SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.WRAPPED)
```

Their SOAP version may have also changed.  I'm no expert on Java web services, but [this discussion](http://www.coderanch.com/t/501314/Web-Services/java/Simple-Unwrapped-Wrapped-SOAP-messages) is informative on both SOAP and Java web services.

If they are unable or unwilling to make these changes on their end, you can have some control over the bindings on the client side of things.  See [.NET Framework Support for SOAP Formats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4cxy91t2%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).  Basically, you can generate your classes from the WSDL using additional command line parameters with wsdl.exe.

On another note, don't they have versioning on their source code?  Surely their history would reflect which changes they have made to their service or parameters.

Comment: I'd be surprised if they did not have version control on their side, likely subversion, but I don't have access to it and they, unfortunately, are not forthcoming.  It's just frustrating because this is not the first time I've had contracts changed on me.  I always thought of wsdl's as contracts, they could be extended but they weren't to be changed; around here not so much, but you know how that goes.  Thanks for the insights.